# how to findout the implement of the function such as "sys_access" in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I wonder to find out the codes of the function "sys_access", but i could only find it`s declare:(in include\Syscalls.h)

`asmlinkage long sys_access(const char __user *filename, int mode);`

i guess it coded by Assemble, but how could i found that?
by the way , i use the source insight to read the linux kernel...it cannot find the symbol in file *.S . Is there more effective tools to read the linux kernel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find system call source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149621/where-can-i-find-system-call-source-code). Better group them all into one question, or we'd get 350 similar questions :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that you have already downloaded kernel sources (not only headers). This function is implemented in C and placed in fs/open.c:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(faccessat, int, dfd, const char __user *, filename, int, mode)
{
     ...
}

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(access, const char __user *, filename, int, mode)
{
        return sys_faccessat(AT_FDCWD, filename, mode);
}
```

There are a bunch of methods to search trough files contents. In simple cases I prefer the usage of `grep`:

```
$> grep -r "access" /usr/src/linux-2.6/*
```

Comment: I already have the whole kernel sources. grep will get so many results....i think `SYSCALL_DEFINE2` is a marco which make `access` to `sys_access`.The symbol will be built after linked.so i cann`t located the function like this...

Comment: do you have some nice method to find the function like that?

Comment: It is grep. You can use any regular expression you want to make your search easy. For example: `grep -r "SYSCALL_DEFINE.(.*acess.*" /usr/src/linux-2.6/*`. Anyway, regardless of the tool you use to perform search you'll need regexps to find such things.

Comment: [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) can be very useful for navigating such source code. Or [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/). No regular expressions required.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: While I do like tagging tools, I don't think ctags will be able to recognize `SYSCALL_DEFINEn(foo)` as `sys_foo`.  Is there a special configuration that helps with this?  (btw, I personally found that [GNU Global](http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) works well for the kernel source.)