# System calls Implementation

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls

If a user application makes a system call , a software interrupt/exception is triggered. How can I see the source code for generating a software interrupt ?

Comment: You should probably be looking at library source (e.g. libc, either GNU libc or uClibc) rather the kernel source.

Answer (score 9):

It is explained in [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/). And you should read wikipedia [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) page (and also about [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO)), and also [intro(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man pages. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11609768/841108) answer and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10151524/841108) one. Look also inside [Gnu Libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) & [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) source code. Learn also to use `strace` to find out which syscalls are made by a given command or process.

See also the [calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and Application Binary Interface specification relevant to your system. For x86-64 it is [here](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf).

Comment: Right now the [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/hello.html) still explains the deprecated `int 0x80` instead of syscall.

Comment: @ceving: Yes. Feel free to **contribute** to that *Assembly HowTo* to improve it. But I believe few people care about assembly these days, because compilers give better code than human can write, and because of VDSO...

Comment: It is quite the same. Only the numbers and registers differ. An `exit(n)` is `eax=60 edi=n syscall` instead of `eax=1 ebx=n int0x80`.

Answer (score 3):

long long ago, there is an `int 0x80` trap to enter into the kernel, but nowadays `sysenter` is preferred.

you can get the code by dumping `vsyscall` section which mapped into every process automatically by kernel.

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps 
blah blah blah
...
blah blah blah
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

for more information check [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/446528/)

Answer (score 1):

A software interrupt can be triggered with the Intel x86 assembly instruction `int n`, where `n` is the interrupt number. A syscall is a special case of software interrupt; in  you can manually do a syscall by

```
mov eax, m
int 0x80
```

where `m` should be replaced with the interrupt number. Here are lists of [32-bit syscall numbers](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/linux_syscalls_32bit.html) and [64-bit syscall numbers](http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/linux_syscalls_64bit.html) that linked to online manpages for the each function. You also need to pass parameters to the syscall via other registers (`ebx`, `ecx`, etc.), and you can read more about that [here](http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/#syscalls).

This is the most general way to do syscalls because it is independent of external libraries, like libc, and you can implement this in C/C++ if you need to by using inline assembly.

Comment: This is an implementation-specific answer to a general question.

Comment: The links are broken. It might be better to reference the kernel source directly: [32 bit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h?id=refs/tags/v3.2.52) and [64 bit](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_64.h?id=refs/tags/v3.2.52)