# How to interpret PTRACE_PEEKTEXT return value

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, strace

I've been working on a recode of a mini **strace** program without using PTRACE_SYSCALL in order to get familiar with the registers.

So in my code after using ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, ...) to set the user_reg_struct field, I'm using ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, ...) to read from it.

Not really knowing what to do with the retur of that function to use it's data (syscalls etc...), I started looking at some code and I came across things like:

```
int is_a_syscall() {

struct user_reg_struct regs;
unsigned short int ret;

ret = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, regs.rip, 0);
if (ret == 0xFFFF) {
   perror("failed")
   exit(1); }
if (ret == 0x80CD || ret == 0x50F)
   return (true);
return (false);
}
```

Now can someone explain to me what are the numbers in the if() statement, a.k.a:

- **0xFFFF**, I assume it has to do with the architecture of the processor but I couldn't verify it
- **0x80CD** and **0x50F**

I wish to know what they are, where can I find them, can I interpret them and how can I use them to get my system calls and their arguments.

Answer (score 3):

The code you included is somewhat unconventional, so I'll explain what it does and then show a different way to do it.

```
unsigned short int ret;
ret = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, pid, regs.rip, 0);
```

ptrace on Linux returns a long, not an unsigned short. The author of the code is just looking at the low-order 2 bytes of the 4 or 8 bytes that ptrace returns. Since the x86 is [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), this gets the job done, but I'll show another way to do this later.

```
if (ret == 0xFFFF) {
   perror("failed")
   exit(1); }
```

ptrace returns -1 on failure. Since the code stored only the low-order 2 bytes of the return value, and is treating the value as unsigned, the test for -1 uses `0xFFFF` instead.

Since `ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKDATA, ...)` can return -1 even when it succeeds, it would be better to also look at `errno` (I'll show this later).

```
if (ret == 0x80CD || ret == 0x50F)
   return (true);
return (false);
```

You can find opcode lists at sites like http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html . `CD` is `int` and `CD80` is `int 80` and `0F05` is `syscall`. These are two opcodes used in x86 Linux to do system calls. Further info at [What is better “int 0x80” or “syscall”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall).

Here's another way to check for system call instructions (untested):

```
int is_a_syscall(regs)
struct user_reg_struct regs;
{
    long ret;
    unsigned char primary, secondary;
    extern int errno;

    errno = 0;
    ret = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKTEXT, pid, regs.rip, 0);
    if (ret == -1 && errno != 0) {
        perror("failed")
        exit(1);
    }
    primary = (unsigned)0xFF & ret;
    secondary = ((unsigned)0xFF00 & ret) >> 8;
    if (primary == 0xCD && secondary == 0x80 || primary == 0x0F && secondary == 0x05)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

I use the full width of ptrace's return value. If it's -1 and if `errno` has been set, then that indicates an error. I also use `PTRACE_PEEKTEXT` instead of `PTRACE_PEEKDATA`, although on x86 it doesn't matter. Bitmasks are used to get the primary and secondary opcode bytes.

> how can I use them to get my system calls and their arguments.

For this, please see this detailed answer: [What are the calling conventions for UNIX & Linux system calls on x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/2554472).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how do these relate to decimal (e.g. 0x80CD = 32973), or what is their semantic meaning in relation to `ptrace()` (e.g. 0xFFFF probably means the function encountered an error)?

If the former, these are numbers expressed in **hexadecimal**. That is, the number system where the numeral range consists of:  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F.

If the latter, check out the return value section in the [man page for ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html#RETURN_VALUE)