# What's the relationship between VDSO(7) and SYSCALL(2)?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall), I learned

- `syscall` is the default way of entering kernel mode on `x86-64`.
- In practice, recent kernels are implementing a *VDSO*

Then I look up manual, in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html :

> The first table lists the instruction used to transition to kernel
>          mode (which might not be the fastest or best way to transition to the
>          kernel, so you might have to refer to vdso(7)), the register used to
>          indicate the system call number, the register used to return the sys‐
>          tem call result, and the register used to signal an error.....

But I lack some essential knowledge to understand the statements.

Is it true that *VDSO(7)* is the implementation of *syscall(2)*, or *syscall(2)* will invoke *VDSO(7)* to complete **system call**?

If it is not true, what's the relationship between *VDSO(7)* and *SYSCALL(2)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more carefully the man pages [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) and the wikipages on [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and [VDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO). Read also the [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) wikipage and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (freely downloadable).

System calls are fundamental, they are the *only* way a [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) application can interact with the operating system [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)) and use services provided by it. So every program uses some system calls (unless it crashes and is terminated by some [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html)). System calls requires a user to kernel transition (e.g. thru a `SYSCALL` or `SYSENTER` machine [instruction on x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings)) which is somehow "costly" (e.g. could take a microsecond).

VDSO is only a clever optimization (to avoid the cost of a genuine system call, for very few functions like [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) which also still exist as genuine system calls), a bit like some shared library magically provided by the kernel without any real file. Some programs (e.g. statically linked ones, or those not using `libc` like [BONES](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/) or probably [busybox](https://busybox.net/)) don't use it.

You can avoid VDSO (or not use it), and earlier kernels did not have it. But you cannot avoid doing system calls, and programs usually do a lot of them.

Play also with [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand the (many) system calls done by an application or a running process.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration, the question actually is raised from ostep (chapter 6)which you just mentioned, though not directly. I learn much about the relationship between they two. this is quite a awesome answer:P

Comment: Oh, quite sorry, it is a typo, "If you can come, I will feel honored".

Answer (score 2):

the VDSO(7) is not the implementation of syscall(2).
Without VDSO(7), syscall will be run in user-space applications. In this case will be occur context switching.
if use VDSO(7), will be run syscall without context switching.
The kernel automatically maps into the address space of all user-space applications with vDSO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, vongasy :P it seems i must learn much more deep. I am ready!