# segfault for simple close program in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I just started to learn assembly by following "Programming From The Ground Up" and already hit my first issue with the first ever program. I got a segfault for the following code which is supposed to be an exit program:

```
.section .data

.section .text

.global _start
_start:
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %edi
    int $0x80
```

I've looked into it and one thing suggested was to not use `int $0x80` anymore since its a [legacy way to invoke system call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall-in-32-bit-code-on-linux#:%7E:text=syscall%20is%20the%20default%20way,32%20bit%20modes%20of%20operation.&text=int%200x80%20is%20a%20legacy,call%20and%20should%20be%20avoided.) so I tried to use `syscall` instead but it didn't fix it.

the commands I used are as follow:

```
as test.s -o test.o
ld test.o -o test
./test
```

I am using the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I tried to look at it in a debugger and what I found was that after my code, there would be an endless stream of `add %al, (%rax)` with each memory address from `0x40100c` and onwards having this line.

I have absolutely no idea what is happening and would appreciate any help.

Comment: It works for me.  What commands are you using to assemble, link and run the program?  And you are running this on a Linux system, correct?

Comment: @NateEldredge Im using `as` to assemble and `ld` to link and to run im simply just doing `./`

Comment: The `add %al, (%rax)` is normal; the rest of the page following your code is filled with 0 bytes, which happen to be the encoding of the instruction `add %al, (%rax)`.  It shouldn't matter because if your `exit` system call works, those bytes will never be executed.

Comment: The full, exact commands please.  The options you use are important.  And please edit them into the question; in comments they are hard to read and may get deleted.

Comment: `as test.s -o test.o` for the assemble, `ld test.o -o test` to link and then `./test` to run

Comment: Running those exact commands successfully builds and runs the program for me, with no segfault.  I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64.  You're sure this is the source code you're building?  (For instance, you saved your source file in your editor before assembling?)

Comment: Are you using Windows Subsystem for Linux?  (Although that would normally make int 0x80 itself segfault, at least WSL v1).  If not, what distro are you using?  Are you sure you built this exact source, with EAX=1, the correct `__NR_exit` for 32-bit code?  (BTW, the 32-bit int 0x80 ABI takes its first arg in EBX, although that's already 0 in `_start` in a static executable.)

Comment: Also, try running `strace ./test` to see what system call it thinks you're making.

Comment: Note for your `syscall` test that you can't simply replace `int $0x80` with `syscall` and nothing else; they use different registers and different system call numbers.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256967/634919.  You'll have to replace `movl $1, %eax` with `movl $60, %eax`.

Comment: I am using the WSL, I should have mentioned that in the post I do apologize.

Comment: Ok, so does the exact code in your question actually segfault?  Or are you using WSL2 where a real Linux kernel runs in a VM, so it can support CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION?  [edit] to include full details, and result of running under strace.  And make sure the code block in the question matches what you're actually running.

Comment: I am running WSl 1 so I'll download WSL 2 and see if that fixes the issue, if not I'll update you with more information. Other than the the exact code was what was run and as for strace this was what I got: `execve("./exit", ["./exit"], 0x7fffded5c6c0 /* 19 vars */) = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SI_KERNEL, si_addr=NULL} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV (core dumped) +++
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @PeterCordes yes so having as WSL1 was the issue, it works on WSL 2. Thank you very much

Comment: Yup, if you want to follow examples from a book / tutorial, don't try to port them to a different ISA / system-calling convention while you're still learning the basics they're trying to teach.  See [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861903) for how to build an actual 32-bit binary, instead of using 32-bit system calls in a 64-bit binary.