# nasm write system call not working for 64 bit version how to resolve?

Tags: linux, nasm, system-calls

I have written simple `hello_world` program in `nasm`.

```s
segment .text               ; code section
    global _start           ; must be declared for linker

    _start:                 ; tell linker entry point
        mov edx, len        ; message len (DX is for data register)
        mov ecx, msg        ; message to write (CX is for count register)
        mov ebx, 1          ; (stdout) file descriptor
        mov eax, 1          ; system call number for write system call
        int 0x80            ; call kernel

        mov eax, 1          ; system call number for exit system call
        int 0x80            ; call kernel

section .data
    msg db "Hello, World", 0xa
    len equ $ - msg
```

so when i am compiling this program with `elf64` flag
`$nasm -f elf64 hello_world.nasm`

and then linking with `ld`
`$ld hello_world.o`

finally when i ran `a.out` it not write anything to `stdout`.

when i opened file `unistd_64.h` to show which system call is calling for no 1.

```c
// /usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h

#ifndef _ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H
#define _ASM_X86_UNISTD_64_H 1

#define __NR_read 0
#define __NR_write 1
#define __NR_open 2
#define __NR_close 3
#define __NR_stat 4
```

As you can see for write system call number is `1`. this program will work if i put `4` instead of `1` but `4` is specified in `unistd_32.h` and i also compiled with `elf64` flag so why it is not working for `64 bit`?

for your reference `unistd_32.h`

```c
#ifndef _ASM_X86_UNISTD_32_H
#define _ASM_X86_UNISTD_32_H 1

#define __NR_restart_syscall 0
#define __NR_exit 1
#define __NR_fork 2
#define __NR_read 3
#define __NR_write 4
```

Comment: Related: [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) - `int 0x80` invokes the 32-bit ABI, with numbers from `unistd_32.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a mistake in which you need to use the [sysv-64-abi](https://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) which states that functions parameters to be passed to rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx. In addition `exit` syscall number is decimal 60 not 1. also you mistyped `section .text`. Any you need to use `syscall` and not old slower `int` soft interrupt instruction to trap into kernel.

```
section .text               ; code section
    global _start           ; must be declared for linker

    _start:                 ; tell linker entry point
        mov rdx, len        ; message len (DX is for data register)
        mov rsi, msg        ; message to write (CX is for count register)
        mov rdi, 1          ; (stdout) file descriptor
        mov rax, 1          ; system call number for write system call
        syscall            ; call kernel

        mov rax, 60          ; system call number for exit system call
        syscall            ; call kernel

section .data
    msg db "Hello, World", 0xa
    len equ $ - msg
```

Comment: can you give me reason why you used `syscall` instead of `int 0x80` because when i used `syscall` it works.

Comment: @Visrut ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12806584/what-is-better-int-0x80-or-syscall-in-32-bit-code-on-linux```

Comment: `syscall` is not a function call. We indeed want to follow the SysV convention for it, but we can't fully adhere it, because the 4th argument register for `syscall` can't be `rcx` as `rcx` will be clobbered by the nature of `syscall` instruction itself to save the next `rip` when it returns to userspace.

Comment: So the registers usage to pass argument to `syscall` will be `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `r10`, `r8`, `r9` respectively. Just to emphasize... Yes, it is `r10`, not `rcx`