# Difference between system API and system call API

Tags: linux, api, system-calls, terminology

I have read "system call APIs are for user-space access and
system APIs are for system space access". I am new to Linux OS concepts, I don't have any knowledge about the System API. Can anyone explain the difference between these two?

Comment: Where did you read that sentence? Can you provide an URL?

Comment: I have read this from a pdf that was provided my trainer. I think he has got it from the Charles Crowley's book.

Answer (score 4):

A system call is an explicit request to the kernel made via a software interrupt. It is the lowest level thing which talks to the Operating system. System call is when you call the kernel. System-calls are actually intended to be very low-level interfaces, you can say to a very specific functionality which your program cannot accomplish on its own.

Whereas a System API are used to invoke system call

Comment: sure.  i have another question. which applications are executed on user space and system space,can you provide me with the examples and also help me with a website link where I can read more on the memory management.(a good one).

Comment: okay.not a problem.don't know the rules since  I am a new member.

Answer (score 1):

Read [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) and [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) wikipages first.

As [Rahul Triparhi answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20172158/841108), system calls are the elementary operations, as seen from a [user-mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28computer_security%29) application software. Use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to find out which syscalls are done by some program.

The system calls are well documented in the section 2 of the `man` pages (type first `man man` in a terminal on your Linux system). So read [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) and then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html).

<sup>Stricto sensu, syscalls have an interface, notably specified in [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specifications like [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf), defined at the lowest possible machine level - in terms of machine instructions and registers, etc... The functions in section 2 are tiny C wrappers above them. See also [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/)</sup>

Please read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) which explains quite well many of them.

BTW, I am not sure that "System API" has a well defined meaning, even if I guess what it could be. See also the several answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12776340/841108).

Probably "System API" refers to the many functions standardized by [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), implemented in the [POSIX C library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library) such as [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (but you could use some other `libc` on Linux, like [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/), if you really wanted to). I am thinking of functions like [dlopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/dlopen.html) (to dynamically load a plugin) or [getaddrinfo(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) (to get information about some network things) etc... The Linux implementation (e.g. [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)) is providing a super-set of it.

More generally, the section 3 of man pages, see [intro(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/intro.3.html), is providing a lot of library functions (most of them built above system calls, so `dlopen` actually calls [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall, and `getaddrinfo` may use syscalls to connect to some server - see [nsswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html), etc...). But some library functions are probably not doing any syscall, like [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [sqrt(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sqrt.3.html) or [longjmp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/longjmp.3.html) .... (they are just doing internal computations without needing any additional kernel service).